# Vue.js not updating props in child when parent component is changing the property

Tags: javascript, security, vue.js

I am trying to communicating between component I have structure like

```
<div id=chat-box>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <chat-header></chat-header>
    <message-container :chat="chat"></message-container>
    <chat-compose @clicked="onClickChild"></chat-compose>
  </div>
</div>
```

parent

```
methods: {
onClickChild (value) {
  console.log('in top parent');
  this.chat = value;
},
```

child 1

```
methods: {
  startChat: function(event) {
    this.$emit('clicked', new chat({
     type: 'user',
     message: this.input_value,
     button: 'user',
     metaInfo: 'user',
     isBot: false,
   }))
  },
},
```

child 2

export default {
  name: 'messageContainer',
  props: ['chat'],

```
data: function() {
  return {
    chatSession: [],
  }
},

method : {
  updateData : function() {
    console.log('called updatedata');

  }
},

created: function () {
  console.log(this.chat) 
},
mounted: function () {
 console.log(this.chat) 
},

updated: function() {
  console.log(this.chat)
}
```

}

Here on clickChild method is emitting the parent method which is updating the chat object but message-container component not getting the updated value it is showing default initialized value even not rendering again on data changes I tried created, mounted and updated method also to get the updated value these method are calling only once at the time of app initialization never calling again on data changes

Basically here are three component one is parent and other two are child so one child is updating the chat object and emitting to parent and parent passing same updated child to another child but the another child not getting re-render or getting the updated value
so please help am I doing wrong or there are other way to achieve it.

Comment: Did you define `chat` as a data property on your parent component?

Comment: @yes I defined that

Answer (score 7):

This is probably due to Vue caching the `<message-container>` component.

Try adding a :key the component to force it to re-render.

```
 <message-container :chat="chat" :key="count"></message-container>
```

Add a counter to your `onClickChild` method

```
onClickChild(value){
   this.chat = value;
   this.count = this.count + 1;
}
```

Comment: chat is an object so its giving Avoid using non-primitive value as key, error

Comment: I modified my answer to add a different key.  Be sure to add the `count` variable to your `data` array.

Comment: Thanks, it help me a-lot

Answer (score -1):

You added an event called "clicked". You should use "click" instead.

```
<chat-compose @click="onClickChild"></chat-compose>
```

If you want to create "clicked" event, you need to specify this inside your chat-compose component.

Basically, you will receive a custom component event and emit a response/something.

## For custom components events:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

---

If you want to send a message to the parent, you can use:

`this.$parent.chat = ...`

or

Create a global event bus, to keep all events in one place (depending on the size/complexity of your application, this can be a good solution). You can read about it here: https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: its not event "click" its callback method name which will call while child emit the event and its working as expected. 
Mine problem is one child is updating the chat object and emit to parent and parent passing the same object to another child as props but the second child not getting re-render or getting updated value so what exact method should be used to listen the updated child from method created mounted or updated but no one method are getting called when parent  is called from first child and object is updated and same passed to second child

Comment: @Eduardo Stuart: i downvoted because he IS emitting a "clicked" event in his "chat-compose" component. (@DeepakPatidar: you should use some punctuation in your sentences, to make them more readable.)